# centering the position of blinking cursor without changing the position of placeholder

Tags: html, css, cursor, placeholder

I am working on a [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) in which I want to center the position of a blinking cursor with placeholder centered as well.

At this moment on placeholder `what are you looking for...`, the blinking cursor starts from all the way from the left as shown below.

[image]

The CSS codes which I have used for the placeholder and the blinking cursor are:

**Blinking Cursor**:

```
.input-searchicon input{
padding-left: 40px;
}
```

**Placeholder:**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 text-align: center;


}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
 text-align: center;  


}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
 text-align: center;


}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
 text-align: center; 


}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS codes above so that the **blinking cursor starts from the center with placeholder centered as well.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of  input also should be center. change the style of input to this:

```
.input-searchicon input{
   padding-left: 40px;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509566/how-to-make-a-form-which-searches-an-item-around-a-specific-radius?noredirect=1#comment89988295_51509566). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `text-align: center` on the `input`.

```css
.input-searchicon{
  text-align: center;
}


::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 text-align: center;


}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
 text-align: center;  


}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
 text-align: center;


}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
 text-align: center; 


}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for" class="input-searchicon"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have a similar question. I am wondering if you can give me [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509566/how-to-make-a-form-which-searches-an-item-around-a-specific-radius) how to proceed on that question.

Comment: @user5447339 No problem.